# An inequality about uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $$ ||f'||_{\infty} \leq 4 ||f||_{\infty} ||f''||_{\infty}$$

I tried to prove this using the generalized mean value theorem but couldn't. Also writing $f'$ in its limit definition and trying to use the taylor expansion of $f(x+h)$ was also an idea but didn't bring me to the end.

Thanks for any hints and proofs!

Comment: Using the Taylor expansion of $f(x+h)$ is the right idea here.  Choose the value of $h$ that gets you the best possible upper bound for $f'$.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ are bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint provided by Rudin's $\textit{Principles of Mathematical Analysis}$.

Hint: If $h>0$, Taylor's theorem shows that
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2h}[f(x+2h)-f(x)]-hf''(\xi)
\end{align}
for some $\xi \in (x, x+2h)$. Hence
\begin{align}
|f'(x)| \leq h\|f''\|_\infty + \frac{\|f\|_\infty}{h}.
\end{align}
then set 
\begin{align}
h = \sqrt{\frac{\|f\|_\infty}{\|f''\|_\infty}}.
\end{align}

Comment: @JeanMarie You forgot the square root.

Comment: @JeanMarie what do you want me to elaborate more on when you say "I don't understand the global reasoning and deduction you do..."?

Comment: @JeanMarie where's your square root?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's a pointwise bound, what do you mean "its 2-norm".

Comment: I mean that sup $|f'(x)|^2$ is not $\|f'\|_{\infty}.$ There is a square that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @JeanMarie Unfortunately, the problem is actually wrong as stated by OP.

Comment: Rudin problem 5.15

Comment: Sorry, I have not this book... But do you mean 1) That the inequality as stated by the OP has counterexamples and/or 2) That the inequality given in the book of Rudin is different ?

Comment: Besides, I erase my questions, note for erasing the trace of my successive misunderstandings, but because they pollute the site

Comment: The estimate is sharp according to the problem.

Comment: See the answer I have given.

Comment: Jackie, please, you should 1) Somewhat revise (at least the end of) your text because it proves something else that what is asked, knowing that what is asked is **erroneous**... 2) (if you agree) erase all the commentaries as I have done for most of them, because they will puzzle anybody who tries to understand what is going on.

Comment: Besides, I haven't understood what you mean when you say "the estimate is sharp according to the problem".

Comment: It would be desirable that you state in the body of your answer that the inequality as written in the question doesn't generally hold, not only in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

We assume, as remarked by @Jonas Meyer, that $f$ is such that $f$ and $f'$ are bounded on $\mathbb{R}.$

In fact, inequality

$$\tag{1}||f'||_{\infty} \leq 4 ||f||_{\infty} ||f''||_{\infty}$$

**cannot hold for all** $f \in C^2$ by lack of homogeneity.

Let us use "reductio ad absurdum". Let us assume there exist a non-zero function  that fullfills (1) with $>0$ values on each side. (such a function exist, e.g., $f:x \mapsto 1/(1+x^2)).$

Then replacing $f$ by $\alpha f$ with $\alpha>0$, and cancelling $\alpha$, we have:

$$||f'||_{\infty} \leq 4 \alpha ||f||_{\infty} ||f''||_{\infty}$$

Taking $\alpha$ sufficiently small results in a contradiction.

The correct inequality should be:

$$\tag{2}||f'^2||_{\infty} \leq 4 ||f||_{\infty} ||f''||_{\infty}$$

as can be easily established by terminating the "proof" of Jacky Wong.

A direct consequence of (2) is that the boundedness of $f$ and $f''$ implies the boundedness of $f'^2$.